# Displaying output with JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

How can I display an output string from my method using `JOptionPane`, when my output has a number of variations due to an `if` loop in my method? 
For example:

```
public static int ballpath(int NumberOfSlot) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfSlot; i++) {
        if (Math.random() * 10 <= 5) {
            String output3 = "R";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output3);
        } else {
            String output4 = "l";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output4);
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();
}
```

How do I use `JOptionPane` to display either `"l"` or `"R"` when I call on the method in my program?
p.s the last bit of code `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();`isnt complete cause i dont know how to display the output

Comment: It is currently unclear what your problem with this current code is (except the missing return statement). It does what you want it to do (show either "l" or "R"). Or do you want to build a single String with the `for` loop (like "RRlRll") and print the whole String, instead of each letter separately?

Comment: are you sure you need a for loop . this will give you so many joption panes.next joption pane will be visible once you close the visible one.

Comment: i want it to build a single String with the for loop

Comment: When you write a question, then clearly state what your issue is. That you're trying to create a complete String is crucial information, so don't add that later in the comments. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String output = "";  
   for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfSlot; i++) {
        output = Math.random() * 10 <= 5 ? output+"R" : output+"L";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    //edited the answer according to op's last comment.
```

declare a `String` named `output` outside the `forloop` , you can then change it within your `conditions`. then open the `joption pane` at the end.

Comment: You notice, that your code does just the same as OPs code, right? And mind that OP commented after your answer: *"i want it to build a single String with the for loop"*.

Comment: except the part printing a empty joption pane at the end.

Comment: And that part is what OP is asking about ... good that your answer omitted that ;P.

Comment: op clearly mention in his post that he want to print "R" or "L" what am i supposed to do after that ?. anyway edited my post.

Comment: I guess we can both agree that the question is quite unclear and badly asked. I linked him the help page about asking question, so this may improve in the future.

Comment: thx 
sorry if the question was poorly asked
but i got my answer 
thx a  lot guys

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very unclear (do you want to show a bunch of joptionpanes?), but this may be what you want:

```
String output = "";
for (int x = 0; x < NumberOfSlot; x++)
{
    if (Math.random() * 10 <= 5) {
        output+="R";
    } else {
        output+="l";
    }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```

Please provide some more information, though.

Comment: How do I use JOptionPane to display either "l" or "R" ?. which part of your code does that